# Remove padlocks icons from public services Spring boot openapi v2 swagger

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openapi, swagger-ui

According to the picture you see I have several services. Some of them need authorization but some of them are public services that don't need authorization. But in Swagger UI all of the services have padlocks icons. I want to remove the padlock icon from public services. How can I configure it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@SecurityRequirements()` annotation for concerned APIs methods.